# What is the best practice for preparing 'User Posts Page' and letting user use their specific URL to reach their posts page?

Tags: php, post

I am implementing project with LAMP. It is like a simple craiglist. People add their posts deals, etc.
I need a way to let users have their posts URL after they submit (Like Craiglist) so that they can save it and visit later. However I am not sure what is the way of doing this.

Basically I want to show them their posts whenever they visit the url I gave them. 
for example: "mywebpage/posts.php?=/user-post-key". 
             "mywebpage/posts.php?=/user2-post2-key".

Should I have a posts.php file and  parse url after '?=' to decide what I am gonna fill page with?

Above example was just my idea, it may not make sense sorry.
Any suggestions would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need a `posts.php` file and depending on the parameters passed with the `url` you may show specific post, for example, if you have a `url` something like this

```
mywebpage/posts.php?key=user-post-key
```

Then you may retrieve the key in your `posts.php` using something like this

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
if(!empty($key)) {
    // you have a key
}
```

The `url` given in your question (`mywebpage/posts.php?=/user-post-key`) is not in right format. If you pass parameters with url, then it should be like this

```
http://example.com/somePage.php?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

These parameters will be available in the `$_GET` array and you can retrieve parameters with their corresponding key, for example, to retrieve the `value1` in `somePage.php` file from given `url` above, you may use

```
$value1 = $_GET['param1'];
```

You may also construct a `url` like this

```
http://example.com/somePage.php/value1/value2
```

In this case, you have to do some extra work/mapping but you may use `$_GET` approach, check [this artilce](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/), written about pretty url but you may find more on the internet, also look this article for [user input sanitation](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/).

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize values which comes from the user. So every $_GET or $_POST variable could hold a value which tries to attack your application.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER, Thanks for mentioning this, [This is an article about it](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/).

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I guess I can use some regex to accept variables only in a format I want, right?

Comment: @user2940463 Read the link in the comment above yours from @RCV. You don't need to write for every input type your own regex. You can with `filter_var()`check for valid E-Mail addresses etc. But yes, sometimes you'll have to write your own regex to check if data is delivered in the format you whish.